# Multicast Delegates implement the Builder pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, delegates, builder, multicastdelegate

Is the use of multicast delegates an appropriate way to implement the Builder design pattern?

The reason I ask is because my concept/understanding of the Builder pattern is a collection of methods that can be combined/rearranged like LEGO blocks. So you might have the following methods:

```
void Shave(int StrokeCount) { ... }
void FeedTheDog(int Cups) { ... }
void MakeCoffee(int Cups) { ... }
void Shower(int Temperature) { ... }
```

...that can be mixed-and-matched/LEGO'd together, so that one morning you call:

```
Shower()
FeedTheDog()
MakeCoffee()
```

...another morning:

```
Shower()
Shave()
FeedTheDog()
MakeCoffee()
```

...another morning:

```
MakeCoffee()
FeedTheDog()
Shower()
```

(etc. &c. ad infinitum ad nauseum)

And since multicast delegates allow you to add same-signatured methods to an instance of the delegate, and they will fire in the order you add them, there seems to be a semantic connection here (in my mind/to my current way of thinking, anyway). I may be wrong, though, that's why I ask.

Comment: Guess it depends on whether you are building a delegate invocation list.

Comment: I'm not sure how the two are related.  Can you give an example of using multicast delegates with the Builder pattern?

Comment: @Kevin: I'll answer above, as it's more than just a few lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see the advantage of using multicast delegates for the Builder pattern unless you wanted to defer the method execution for some reason.  I have never had this requirement but that's not to say it couldn't be useful.  If you had a scenario where one class was responsible for "preparing the recipe" and another for "cooking the recipe", I guess it could be useful.  Even then, though, you would be limited to only using methods that have the same signature. This is just my opinion though.